# Run a python function for each line in a text file

Tags: python, replace, format, find

Ok so I am trying to mass format a large text document to convert

```
#{'000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009'}
```

into

```
#{'000':'001','002':'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009'}
```

using python and have my function working, however it will only work if I run it line by line.

and was wondering how to get it to run for each line on my input
so that it will work on a multi line document

```
with open("input") as core:
    a = core.read()

K = '!'
N = 12

res = ''
for idx, ele in enumerate(a):

    if idx % N == 0 and idx != 0:
        res = res + K
    else:
        res = res + ele

b = (str(res).replace(",",":").replace("!",","))

l = len(b) 
c = b[:l-1]
d = c + "}"

print(d)
```

here is the current result for a multiline text file

```
{'000':'001','002':'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009',
{'001':'00,':'003':'00,':'005':'00,':'007':'00,':'009':'00,'}
{'002':',03':'004':',05':'006':',07':'008':',09':'000':',01'}
{'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009','000':'001','002'}
```

So Far I have tried

```
with open('input', "r") as a:
    for line in a:

        K = '!'
        N = 12

        res = ''
        for idx, ele in enumerate(a):

            if idx % N == 0 and idx != 0:
                res = res + K
            else:
                res = res + ele

        b = (str(res))

        l = len(b) 
        c = b[:l-1]
        d = c + "}"

print(d)
```

but no luck

FOUND A SOLUTION

```
import re

with open("input") as core:
    coords = core.read()

sword = coords.replace("\n",",\n")

dung = re.sub('(,[^,]*),', r'\1 ', sword).replace(",",":").replace(" ",",").replace(",\n","\n")

print(dung)
```

I know my solution works, but i cant quite apply this to other situations where I am applying different formats based on the need.
Its easy enough to work out how to format a single line of text as there is so much documentation out there.

Does anybody know of any plugins or particular python elements where you can write your format function and then apply it to all lines.
like a kind of applylines() extension instead of readlines()

Comment: Ah, a bit late with my solution. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in this way:

```
# Read in the file
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace(',', ':')

# Write the file out again
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Im trying to change every 2nd comma to a colon starting on the first comma in each line

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the file contents per line and then apply the text processing functions on each line. After that just append the lines to the response output. The code would be

```
with open("input") as core:
    a = core.read()

K = '!'
N = 12
a = a.split("\n")
res = ''

for line in a:
  temp = ''
  for idx, ele in enumerate(line):
      if idx % N == 0 and idx != 0:
          temp = temp + K
      else:
          temp = temp  + ele
  temp = (str(temp).replace(",",":").replace("!",","))
  res = res+temp[:-1]+"}\n"
res = res[:-1]
print(res)
```

For the following input

```
{'000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009'}
{'000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009'}
```

the output would be:

```
{'000':'001','002':'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009'}
{'000':'001','002':'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would base an answer off of turning your input data into a generator so that I could apply `next()` to it to take two items at a time.

```py
def clean_line(line):
    items = iter(line.split(","))
    return ','.join(f'{item}:{next(items)}' for item in items)
```

With a method like `clean_line()` you might now use:

```py
data = [
    "{'000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009'}",
    "{'000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009'}"
]
results = "\n".join(clean_line(line) for line in data)
print(results)
```

Or reading from a file as:

```py
def clean_line(line):
    items = iter(line.strip("\n").split(","))
    return ','.join(f'{item}:{next(items)}' for item in items)

with open("data.txt", "r") as file_in:
    results = "\n".join(clean_line(line) for line in file_in.readlines())
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your given example input, you can read the whole file at once using `.read()`, use a pattern to match the first comma, and capture in group 1 matching until the second comma.

In the replacement use `:` and a backreference to what is captured in group 1 using `\1`

```
,([^,\n]*,)?
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `,` Match a comma
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^,\n]*,` Optionally match any character except a comma or a newline, then match a comma
- `)?` Close the capture group and make it optional

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OeEVgu/1)

For example:

```
import re

with open("input") as core:
    dung = re.sub(r",([^,\n]*,)?", r":\1", core.read())
    print(dung)
```

Ouput

```
#{'000':'001','002':'003','004':'005','006':'007','008':'009'}
```